# NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object (asp.net core)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

i try to show a list of names in a drop down list , in this page html , but I get this error .
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMeJH.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTVKf.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0T7p.png)

there is a solution for this ?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the `model` you constructed to your view using
`return View(model);`